# (C++) Initialize string with HUGE amount of text, not from txt

Tags: c++, string, text, initialization

I have a quick question that I think has a quick answer. I have a string variable and I need it to be filled with predetermined characters. The problem is, I have A LOT to put in it. How can I fill that string with all that text without having a huge ("lotsandlotsoftext"); when I declare it? I don't want it to be in a separate text file.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want it to be in a separate file, then it needs to be in your source file. There is no `get_my_string_from_nowhere` function.

Comment: Is it "oneBigBlockOfText" or can it be aggregated somehow, like string s = "abc"; s += "def"; ...

Comment: I have never messed with any resource or header files. Is there something I can put in there and have my program fill a string from it? I just don't want it in my main cpp file.

Comment: It is one big block of text about 4kb in size that is not generated from user input.

Comment: I believe you can technically do something like `std::string text{#include "text.txt"};` (on new lines).

Comment: I do not want it to be in a separate text file outside the program. When I compile it, I want it to just be in my program somewhere.

Comment: @user2356609, It will be in your program when you compile it. The PP does a copy-paste.

Comment: Then I am able to delete txt afterwards and it will be fine?

Comment: @user2356609, Until you recompile. If you don't want it in your main file, and you don't want it in another file, where do you want it?

Comment: As long as the final .exe contains a string with that info and I dont have an additional text.txt tagged along Im fine

Comment: what about using the resources of your program ? are you using windows or unix? what complier? define a resource and use it that way..

Comment: write the string in a header file and access it through a const char pointer.

Comment: @user2356609, Well, that PP method, among others, would not require a separate file with the executable.

Comment: I included how to use the resources..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a string resource to load up your std::string.

1) Add string to the Resource Editor:
[How to Add a string resource in visual studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

2) then use LoadString

3) then use that LoadedString as a parameter to your constructor

```
    TCHAR buf[<yourverylongstringlength>]; 
    LoadString(hInst, IDS_YOURSTRINGRESOURCE, buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    const std::string YourCPlusPlusString = buf;
```

[MSDN LoadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Example of Using LoadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#creating_child)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. each character is different

Comment: ahhh gotchya. You do not want it to be in another file and you do not what to type it? From where would you like the complier to get it then?

Comment: It will be the same characters every time the program is run. I just dont want it to fill up my whole project or require a text.txt file along with my .exe

Comment: cool then use a string resource, it will be very simple. you using Visual Studio on windows?

Comment: yes visual studio 2008 (lol), windows 7. Ive never used resources except for icons.

Comment: cool can you accept the answer and / or one up it then please?

Comment: Note: The maximum length of a Win32 string resource is 4096 characters.